# No me deja entrar como usuario en phpMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

No se como entrar como usuario en phpMyAdmin.

le doy al logotipo de la puertecita pero no hay manera y no se que hacer, estoy en busca de conectar mi aplicación a la base de datos online para mi proyecto final.

Comment: ¿Muestra algún mensaje de error en alguna parte? Si es así agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. De todos modos, si estás trabajando en un proyecto supongo que la conexión la harás por código, en el lenguaje en que hayas programado el proyecto, no veo qué sentido tiene querer conectarte por la interfaz gráfica phpmyadmin ¿?

Answer (score 1):

En la página principal, haga clic en el enlace Cuentas de usuarios, para crear un nuevo usuario, haga clic en el enlace Agregar cuenta de usuario en la pantalla Agregar cuenta de usuario:
nombre de usuario: ejemplo_proyecto_1
nombre de host: localhost
contraseña: ejemplo_proyecto_1
Crear base de datos con el mismo nombre: ejemplo_proyecto_1
No olvides al momento de crear el usuario darle todos los privilegios para que puedas acceder.
Si el problema consiste intenta cambiar los puertos del servidor php.